# Flask returns a response without even checking files

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to understand more precisely how Http connections work with Flask, so I tried writing a very simple app and another simple connection with requests:

```
app = Flask('file-streamer')

@app.route("/uploadDumb", methods=["POST"])
def upload_dumb():
    print("Hello")
    return Response(status=200)
```

Then I am sending a big file (1.5 GB) to the endpoint with requests :

```
url = "http://localhost:5000/uploadDumb"
values = {"file": open(file, "rb")}
r = requests.post(url=url, data={}, files=values)
```

I expected Flask to wait for the whole file to be sent, even if the file is useless. However this is not what's happening, instead Flask returns a 200 response very quickly, which causes a BrokenPipeError with my second script.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here ?

Comment: Are you sure that it's Flask and not Requests? Have you tried enabling debug logging? Have you tried uploading files with other tools like curl?

Comment: Yes, I 've tried to implement the same kind of minimal app with django, and there is no problem, it waits for the file to be sent. I also tried using requests and requests-toolbelt and the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that happens because Flask body-parsing is lazy (which is a good thing, actually). So when request comes, Flask only reads headers until body is accessed somehow (through request.data, request.files, request.json(), etc.). So to trigger a full body (and file) upload, try accessing request body to make Flask parse a file, like:

```
_ = request.data
```